# how can i create reports in a java web project?

Tags: java, printing, report

I need to have a preview&print option on some of my pages in order to print some tables containing information.

Is it possible to create a template page containing headers and footers and the information contained in the html table? It's the first time i'm doing this.

I've used once Crystal Reports in c#. Are there any similar plug-ins / sdks available for Java? If so, how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course Jasper Reports will do.

If you already have the data displayed in the page and need it only style differently, you can do it using only CSS - just define appropriate style [for **media**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) type print.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports will be fine for this.